# Who is the contact for CLIPS/R2?

Tags: clips

There was a licensed version of CLIPS, called CLIPS/R2, which was for use in C/C++ implementations.  The website contact information is a fax # which does not connect.  (grossweb.com/pst/clipsr2)  I sent a query using a form in the parent website too, and got no reply.

Does anyone have the source for CLIPS/R2?  Or know where I can get it from?  thanks!

Comment: Have you checked this repo: https://github.com/perusio/clips-cpp-interface or maybe this: http://clipsmm.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Will take a look, thanks!  But I have a code base that was built to use clips/r2, so unless it has all the same function signatures, it would not be an exact fit.